# How to extract phone number and Pin from each text line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Sample Text from the  log file

```
2021/08/29 10:25:37 20210202GL1 Message Params [userid:user1] [timestamp:20210829] [from:TEST] [to:0214736848] [text:You requested for Pin reset. Your Customer ID: 0214736848 and PIN: 4581]
2021/08/27 00:03:18 20210202GL2 Message Params [userid:user1] [timestamp:20210827] [from:TEST] [to:0214736457] [text:You requested for Pin reset. Your Customer ID: 0214736457 and PIN: 6193]
2021/08/27 10:25:16 Thank you for joining our service; Your ID is 0214736849 and PIN is 5949
```

Other wording and formatting can change but **ID** and **PIN** don't change

**Expected out put for each line**

```
0214736848#4581
0214736457#6193
0214736849#5949
```

Below is what I have tried out using bash though am currently able to extract only the numeric values

```
while read p; do 

NUM='' 
counter=1;
text=$(echo "$p" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')

for line in $text
do
if [ "$counter" -eq 1 ] #if is equal to 1
then
 NUM+="$line"  #concatenate string
 else
 NUM+="#$line"  #concatenate string
 fi
 let counter++  #Increment counter
done

printf "$NUM\n"
done < logfile.log
```

Current output though not the expected.

```
2021#08#29#00#03#18#20210202#2#1#20210826#0214736457#0214736457#6193
2021#08#27#10#25#37#20210202#1#1#20210825#0214736848#0214736848#4581
2021#08#27#10#25#16#0214736849#5949
```

Comment: Using sed: `sed -n 's/.*ID: \([0-9]\+\).*PIN: \([0-9]\+\).*/\1#\2/p' file`

Comment: You added a 3rd line of input because [you said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974563/how-to-extract-phone-number-and-pin-from-each-text-line/68974932?noredirect=1#comment121903068_68975653) that that was valid input that my answer wouldn't handle properly, but then you didn't add output for that line to the expected output so we are now confused. If there should be output for that new 3rd line of input then please [edit] your question to show it, if not then please [edit] your question to clarify your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another variation using `gawk` and 2 capture groups, matching 1 or more digits per group:

```
awk '
match($0, /ID: ([0-9]+) and PIN: ([0-9]+)/, m) {
  print m[1]"#"m[2]
}
' file
```

Output

```
0214736848#4581
0214736457#6193
```

---

For the updated question, you could either match `:` or  `is` if you want a more precise match, and the capture group values will be 2 and 4.

```
awk '
match($0, /ID(:| is) ([0-9]+) and PIN(:| is) ([0-9]+)/, m) {
  print m[2]"#"m[4]
}
' file
```

Output

```
0214736848#4581
0214736457#6193
0214736849#5949
```

Comment: Your first answer worked better for me. And I appreciate you for showing me the different ways on how to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using sed capture groups you can do:

```
sed 's/.* Your Customer ID: \([0-9]*\) and PIN: \([0-9]*\).*/\1#\2/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code, you could simple do it with using different field separators. Simple explanation would be, making `Customer ID:`  OR `and PIN:` OR `]$` as field separators and then keeping them in mind printing only 2nd and 3rd fields along with `#` as per required output by OP.

```
awk -v FS='Customer ID: | and PIN: |]$' '{print $2"#"$3}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

With `bash` and a regex:

```
while IFS='] ' read -r line; do
  [[ "$line" =~ ID:\ ([^\ ]+).*PIN:\ ([^\ ]+)] ]]
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}#${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done <file
```

Output:

```
0214736848#4581
0214736457#6193
```

Comment: This too works and I think it may work  better since am using bash script. But the awk solution you posted before and this one, which one consumes less resources?

Comment: For a file with many lines I would prefer `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: Even for a file without many lines awk or sed would be briefer, clearer, easier to write without any gotchas, at least as efficient, and more portable so there's no scenario I can think of where an awk or sed solution wouldn't be preferable to a shell loop for just manipulating text as we're doing here. @Baguma see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 3):

Given the updated input in your question then using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed 's/.* ID[: ][^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).* PIN[: ][^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1#\2/' file
0214736848#4581
0214736457#6193
0214736849#5949
```

---

Original answer:

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v OFS='#' '{print $18, $21+0}' file
0214736848#4581
0214736457#6193
```

Comment: This is not solving my problem as the text is dynamic. Only the words **ID** and **PIN** are the keys I have to look for in this case. Example of another text is  show below
`Thank you for joining our service; Your ID is 0214736849 and PIN is 5949`

Comment: It may not be solving the problem you really have, but it's solving the problem you told us you have. Please [edit] your question to include more truly representative sample input and expected output including cases where the script I posed won't work so we can help you with your real problem.

Comment: Thank you but importantly I have at least learn't something from you.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer to match your updated sample input.